# MQ error 2195 when disconnecting from QueueManager

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, mq

I'm getting an MQException with error code 2195 when disconnecting from the QueueManager. I'm unable to find the reason to this. How can I find out the reason to this exception?

My code looks like this. The last line is throwing the exception.

```
        MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
        MQQueue fromQueue = null;

        try
        {
            // mq properties
            Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _config.HostName);
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _config.Port);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _config.ChannelName);
            // managed mode
            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

            // create connection
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(_config.QueueManagerName, properties);
            fromQueue = qMgr.AccessQueue(_config.QueueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
            gmo.WaitInterval = Convert.ToInt32(timeout.TotalMilliseconds % Int32.MaxValue);

            try
            {
                MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
                fromQueue.Get(message, gmo);       //wait for message

                if (message != null && message.MessageLength > 0)
                {
                    string strMsg = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
                    ret = true;
                }
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ReasonCode != MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)                      
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (fromQueue != null)
                    fromQueue.Close();
                if (qMgr != null)
                    if(qMgr.IsConnected)
                        qMgr.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Do you have any FDC files?  What version of MQ are you using?

Comment: I don't know about any FDC files. What is those used for? The server version is 7.5 and the client version is 8.0.0.4.

Comment: *.FDC files written by MQ to record errors and dump information about what occurred at the time MQ encountered the error. they can be useful in troubleshoot problems.

Answer (score 0):

> MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT

You are creating a local UOW (Unit of Work) but you never commit or backout the transaction.  Now, for a normal disconnect (vs abnormal or crash), MQ is suppose to automatically commit the message(s).  But you should NEVER reply on MQ doing your work for you.

I would suggest you use MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT unless you really want message retrieval in a UOW but then you need to add commit or backout calls.

> if(qMgr.IsConnected)

This method call is pointless.  All it does is look at the last call's CC & RC values to to determine whether to return true or false.  It does not actually test the connection.  As I said, pointless.

Comment: Thank you. My code is called from inside an TransactionScope. I want the retrieval of a message and a write to a database to be in the same transaction. Do I have to explicitly call commit or rollback even though I'm inside a TransactionScope?